# overvoltage with current less than 50uA

Tags: microcontroller

Let's say we have an arduino or Rpi gpio pin connected to (accidentally?) 12V rail with resistor limiting current to ~50uA. I wonder what will happen to a microcontroller. Will it survive or magic smoke pops out? Well without current limit it's dead for sure but does that very small current change cards a bit?

**Edit:** This is just a theoretical question. I would like to know what happens under given circumstances.

Comment: If there is an input protection diode, and that current is within its design capability, and the chip presents enough load that this cannot cause the power rails to rise above their rating, it may survive.   But many parts do not have a published current rating for the protection diode.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Let's say its operating current is 250-400mA with no protection. Well I know I could add a zener with 220ohm resistor to stay under 25mA max rating of GPIO pin but I wonder if that small current(~50uA) can damage your devices

Comment: These ratings have no relation to each other.   You are talking about the rating of the transistors/FETs, but what is at issue here is the rating of the overvoltage protection diode.  That is rarely published - I do recall seeing a Xilinx app note that gave guidelines on resistor level shifting, but for their parts only.

Comment: @ChrisStratton As far as my knowledge goes there's no protection diodes on Rpi

Comment: Given the pi's apparently robustness to handling in non ESD-protected environments when its GPIOs appear to run directly from the SoC to header pins, there's a good chance you are mistaken about that.

Comment: Most protection diodes are rated for about 3mA to 5mA; more than that can cause damage. If there is no statement of pin injection current *but you know a diode is present*, then 1mA max is a good rule of thumb.

Answer (score 1):

ESD diodes are designed to withstand 3kV impulse from 300pF or steady state of 5mA in most chips.

Your application does not appear to damage this.